# Stored procedure with bcp hangs, but works when run as a script

Tags: freeze, bcp, xp-cmdshell

I've been working on exporting a table to a file, and had problems with the bcp (bulk copy program) part of the procedure locking up. The code worked fine when I ran it as a script, but would generate locked processes when I wrapped it in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found the solution; COMMIT. Namely, I had to wrap the code which truncated and inserted into the table which bcp would be picking up the data from within a BEGIN TRANSACTION...COMMIT. Now the procedure works

I think it is to do with the command
exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @bcp
going outside of the SQL session to the OS. Am I correct, or is there a better explanation?